# fastai ImportError: file too short

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pytorch, spacy, fast-ai

I installed fastai as explained here in my ubuntu machine https://forums.fast.ai/t/wiki-thread-lesson-1/6825/63

However, when i import libraries, i am getting below error message.

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.text import *


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9acdcc7330cd> in <module>
----> 1 from fastai import *        # Quick access to most common functionality
      2 from fastai.text import *   # Quick access to NLP functionality

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .basic_train import *
      2 from .callback import *
      3 #from .callbacks import *
      4 from .core import *
      5 from .basic_data import *

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py in <module>
      1 "Provides basic training and validation with `Learner`"
----> 2 from .torch_core import *
      3 from .basic_data import *
      4 from .callback import *
      5 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py in <module>
      1 "Utility functions to help deal with tensors"
----> 2 from .imports.torch import *
      3 from .core import *
      4 
      5 AffineMatrix = Tensor

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/imports/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .core import *
      2 from .torch import *

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/imports/core.py in <module>
      4 import abc, collections, hashlib, itertools, json, operator, pathlib
      5 import mimetypes, inspect, typing, functools, importlib
----> 6 import html, re, spacy, requests, tarfile, numbers
      7 
      8 from abc import abstractmethod, abstractproperty

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in <module>
      6 
      7 # These are imported as part of the API
----> 8 from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
      9 
     10 from .cli.info import info as cli_info

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from ._classes.model import Model

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from .. import util
---> 12 from ..train import Trainer
     13 from ..ops import NumpyOps, CupyOps
     14 from ..mem import Memory

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thinc/neural/train.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
      2 
----> 3 from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
      4 from .util import minibatch
      5 

optimizers.pyx in init thinc.neural.optimizers()

ops.pyx in init thinc.neural.ops()

ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/murmurhash/mrmr.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: file too short
```

Can anyone help me on this please? I searched on the internet for hours and didn't find any information. Thanks